# JSF - HtmlcommandLink.setOnclick() add additional things to the onclick property while creating dynamic components

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I want to create dynamic components (`HtmlCommandLink`s). When I set the `onClick` property, somehow JSF has added additional things. So it doesn't fire my `javascript` as I expected.
After removing those additional things via FirBug, it works fine.

```
Application app = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication();
HtmlCommandLink link = HtmlCommandLink)app.createComponent(HtmlCommandLink.COMPONENT_TYPE);
link.setId("link1");
link.setValue("ClickMe");
link.setOnclick("fireAlert('someText');");
```

But I see something like this...

```
<a onclick="jsf.util.chain(this,event,'fireAlert(\'someText\')','mojarra.jsfcljs(document.getElementById(\'frmBody\'),{\'frmBody:j_idt15:link1\':\'frmBody:j_idt15:link1\'},\'\')');return false" id="frmBody:j_idt15:link1" h>ClickMe</a>
```

What I want is....

```
<a onclick="fireAlert('someText')" id="frmBody:j_idt15:link1" h>ClickMe</a>
```

I'm using `icefaces`.
Why I can't set that simple text value as my `onClick` value ?

Comment: why don't you try adding them via the XHTML page ? I believe mojarrah(JSF) will always do that , it always adds its own processing specific javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use `h:commandLink` or `ice:commandLink` with rendered attribute.